# How to Enable Scrolling for Python Console Application

Tags: python, python-2.7, scroll, console-application, windows-console

I have a Python (2.7) console application that I have written on Windows (8.1). I have used `argparse.ArgumentParser()` for handling the parameters when executing the program.

The application has quite a few parameters, so when the `--help` parameter is used the documentation greatly exceeds the size of the console window. Even with the console window maximized. Which is fine, but the issue I'm encountering is that the user is unable to scroll up to view the rest of the help documentation. I have configured my windows console properties appropriately, such as the "Window Size" and "Screen Buffer Size". And I have verified that those changes are working, but they only work outside of the Python environment. As soon as I execute a Python script or run a `--help` command for a script, the console properties no longer apply. The scroll bar will disappear from the window and I can no longer scroll to the top to see the previous content.

So basically, I need to figure out how to enable scrolling for my Python console programs. I need scrolling enabled both when executing a script and when viewing the `--help` documentation. I'm not sure how to go about doing that. I have been searching online for any info on the subject and I have yet to find anything even remotely helpful.

At this point, I am completely stuck. So if someone knows how to get scrolling to work, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Right-click on the upper right corner of your Python console windows and select Properties and configure the windows size and screen buffer size in the dialog box that appears — then try `--help` again.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I've already tried that several times and still the same result. That's actually how I initially configured the properties for my console. And as soon as I run `--help` again or execute another Python related command, the scroll bar disappears and I'm unable to scroll.

Any chance you have another suggestion?

Comment: @martineau Oh, and I should mention that when I changed the console properties, I tried on a normal console and a console with Administrator privileges...but I still got the exact same result. And if I open up the console properties again, the settings are still set to the values I changed. So the console settings **are** persisting, but for some reason they have no affect when a Python command is executed.

Comment: Try creating a desktop shortcut to `C:\Python\python.exe` and setting _its_ properties (rather than the properties of `python.exe` itself).

Comment: @martineau Should I be changing the properties on **python.exe**? If so, that could be my problem...because I'm running my scripts and `--help` commands from my Windows console (command prompt - cmd.exe). That's how I've always done it in Windows.

Comment: @martineau I actually just checked the properties for the Python interpreter (i.e. python.exe) and it is configured to allow scrolling.

Comment: If you're doing things that way (by first starting `cmd.exe`), then you should be changing `cmd.exe`'s properties. Personally I use a shortcut to `python.exe` and have never changed that exe's properties (but thought you might be).

Comment: @martineau Yeah, cmd.exe is what I was referring to in my post when I said I changed my console properties. And those property changes are working correctly, up until the point that I execute a Python command. Then all of a sudden the settings are no longer being applied to the console window. It's very strange. 


So basically, the property changes are working correctly in every situation except for when I begin executing a Python script/command.

Comment: @martineau I'm going to move this to a chat, so that I don't upset one of the moderators for all the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107898/discussion-between-cm-dev-and-martineau).

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it from you python script (OK, it is possible, but most probably you don't want to do it). Scrolling depends on environment (Windows or Linux terminal, doesn't matter). So it is up to users to set it up in a way that is good for them.

On Linux you can use `less` or `more`:
`python script.py | less`
it will buffers output from the script and will let user ability to scroll up and down without losing any information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah, I'm familiar with how to that in Linux. And I was able to configure my Windows console to allow me to scroll just fine...but for some reason the console configuration isn't being applied when I start executing Python commands and/or scripts. And I checked to see if the property settings were getting reset or something and they're **not**. All the property changes are persisting as they should, but I'm still getting the same behavior.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can set the necessary properties from within Python? I understand that it may not be the ideal solution. But at this point I need something to use as a workaround until I can get a permanent solution in place.

Answer (score 0):

This, my friend, will allow scrolling on both the dimensions.

```
from ctypes import windll, byref
from ctypes.wintypes import SMALL_RECT

WindowsSTDOUT = windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11)
dimensions = SMALL_RECT(-1, -1, 89, 28) # (left, top, right, bottom)
# Width = (Right - Left) + 1; Height = (Bottom - Top) + 1
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleWindowInfo(WindowsSTDOUT, True, byref(dimensions))
```

In case, you want to **fix** scrolling on any side,

```
import os
os.system('mode horizontalSizeInNumber or horizontalSizeInNumber_setToZero and verticalSizeInNumber')
```

Add this piece of code **before** the above written code.